# Complete Sample of video Creation and on demand token issuance in Azure Media Services

Tags: c#, html, azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to create an elearning system that has videos associated with lessons. When a user gets to a lesson a video needs to play. The videos should not play unless I authenticate that the user can play that video and can play it right now. I'm trying to accomplish this using the azure video player.

I can make this work with azure media services without encryption without issue.

However when I go to do the encryption, the samples are VERY week.

What I'm trying to do is encrypt the video so that it can play on all browsers and have everything that the azure video player needs.

Further, at the time that the user requests to play the video I want to use their authentication with our website to determine if the video should play, and then set the token on the media services.

I would have expected that media services would use oAuth 2 and I could point it at our endpoint with a specific claim required for the specific video the user requested and I would return an auth token or not. But it appears to work backwards from this.

So I've done the following:

1. Gone into the classic portal (because apparently this hasn't been updated to either use the new portal or the new way of doing storage...)
2. Created the Media Services account.
3. Gone to content protection as as best as I can figure from the videos enter Type token for both and json web token.
4. Under issuer for aes and playready I've put in the path to our oAuth provider, but I"m not at all sure what this should be and I can't find any documentation that explains what this should be.
5. Scope: Under ae, the samples have something similar to urn:Portal but under playready this has to be a full URI, which I can't figure out what's supposed to be there.
6. I created the verification keys for both types
7. I have no idea what to put in claims or how this is relevant.
8. License type = non-persistent
9. Passing Video Content to Unknown Outputs I have set to Allowed. I don't know what allowed with constriction does or how it should be setup.
10. Allow test devices is enabled for now.

Then in my encoding stuff I've put in the following after creating the asset from samples:

```
//Add encryption
            var key = CreateEnvelopeTypeContentKey(context, finalAsset);

            var tokenTemplateString = AddTokenRestrictedAuthorizationPolicy(context, key, audience, issuer);

            CreateAssetDeliveryPolicy(context, finalAsset, key);

            var tokenTemplate = TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.Deserialize(tokenTemplateString);

            var rawKey = EncryptionUtils.GetKeyIdAsGuid(key.Id);

            string testToken = TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.GenerateTestToken(tokenTemplate, null, rawKey);
```

But if I try and enable this stuff to get playready, wildvine AND BaselineHttp it all blows up and I cannot find examples of all 3 (which appear to be required for Chrome, Firefox and IE/Edge to work reliably) enabled and working in the code as you'd expect. (note the methods called above are directly from the samples)

Further I can't figure out how to use the verification keys from the portal in this code because I can't find any samples on this.

And presumably this sets up the asset to have it's own authentication. Although I can't tell. But what I want and need to do is have each asset be separately authentication by the asset and by the user and not have the bearer token be usable anywhere else.

At this point I'm completely lost, because the only code I can find to generate the JWT is the test stuff which obviously shouldn't be used in production.

What I'm looking for is code that doesn't use Azure AD and allows me to do my own, so that when a user wants to watch a video, they come to me, I say, yup, you're good, here's your token just for you and only you and no one else that is created just for you in C# in my web api that returns the token in the json response.

Then I want to set it in the security credentials (and put all of the permutations in!) so that it will just work on the browser in question (ie, edge, firefox, chrome, safari) and the player sends that along with the rest and the video just plays no matter what browser.

But since I can neither encrypt the video with the right keys, nor encrypt it for all permutations based on the samples nor find any example of creating the JTW properly based on the shared keys and whatever I need to store in my database based on the encryption process I'm stuck.

So is there a sample somewhere that takes you through this full process to make this work in any web browser when done and generate the encryption for all of them, and the token for the client on a per issue basis?

If not, can someone help answer these questions?

And if this is MS watching this, I'd suggest that you consider giving us the ability to have just the single url in the client, and pass our oAuth2 bearer token (not yours) and have you use that to single sign on with us, and demand a claim passing the asset id and getting a yea/nea to play the video with a timespan their authorized to play it on the specific client involved. If this is possible now, please provide a full sample or instructions on how this can be accomplished because it's very not clear at this point and everything is geared to AD which isn't useful and there are a ton of missing pieces.

Ultimately, I need to be able to live stream this content on the web and on mobile clients AND be able to download this content encrypted and play it on those same mobile clients offline but still encrypted and locked down.  Those last pieces I don't have a clue how to do at this point and I can't find any documentation on either, but I'll ask that separately.

Thanks!

## Bonus Reading

Resources found that are relevant but don't answer the question or only partially answer the question and break other parts:

- [Configure asset delivery policies with .NET SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-configure-asset-delivery-policy/)
- [Use AES-128 dynamic encryption and the key delivery service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-protect-with-aes128/#client_request)
- [Azure Media Player - Protected Content](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#protected-content)
- [Azure Media Player - Playback Technology ("Tech")](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#playback-technology-tech-)
- [How to make Token authorized AES encrypted HLS stream working in Safari](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/)
- [Integrate Azure Media Services OWIN MVC based app with Azure Active Directory](http://gtrifonov.com/2015/01/24/mvc-owin-azure-media-services-ad-integration/)  *(this one appears to be the closest but I've been unable to decouple it from Azure AD)*

Comment: Any change you want to explain how you got this to work?

Comment: They fixed the samples so that they actually work and there is a JWT example available now.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have lot of samples to build customized [Security Token Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token_service) (STS), because each business may have its own requirements and lots of customers are doing integration work (i.e. they already have a token issuer service).

As said, I am happy to help you to complete your workflow. You can email me at yanmf@microsoft.com and I could have a call to troubleshoot your workflow.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Comment: Thank you for assisting. I have emailed you details and am happy to send you my source code if necessary. Looking forward to emailing/speaking with you and getting this sorted.